# What's this movie about a ship getting upside down?

Tags: identify-this-movie

I don't have much memories from this movie I saw on french TV a couple years ago.

- The story is about a ship getting upside down, a group of people have to go to the bottom of the ship, which is now the closest part from the surface
- They get maps from the ship that they have to read upside down in order to escape the drowning boat
- At some point there is a man dying crashed by an elevator
- I remember a big fancy room, with a lot of guests
- It's in color
- Probably 2000's
- I swear this is not Titanic

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like [Poseidon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poseidon_(film)) (2006), a remake of [The Poseidon Adventure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Poseidon_Adventure_(novel)) (1972).

It both movies, the ship is turned upside-down during a New Year's Eve party. Both movies feature a party in a main ballroom where many of the main characters get trapped.

Since the ship is upside-down, they want to make their way to the bottom.

In the 2006 version, a man is crushed by an elevator:

> As they head up, they have to cross an elevator shaft, into which
>   Valentin falls before being crushed by the falling elevator.

I don't remember a similar elevator scene in the 1972 movie.

Both were in color but the 1972 version would be seen as before 2000.

Both movies are not TITANIC (though you may want to shy away from boats called Poseidon, as well).

Answer (score -4):

This is the Poseidon Adventure, or it's 2005 remake off the same name. Or the other 2012 remake of the same name. Or most likely, the 2006 feature version simply titled Poseidon.

Luxury Liner capsized,  passengers must survive as it sinks upside down.  Hilarity ensues. Well no, it's a adventure movie not a comedy.